# Need a macro to sum all GL accounts while excluding a few specific GLs

Tags: vba, macros, accounting

I need a macro that sums all of column H excluding Account #s 52202001 and 51701001 (from column F).

I know I could use this formula

```
=SUMIFS($H$15:$H$12729,$F$15:$F$12729,"<> 52202001", $F$15:$F$12729,"<> 51701001")
```

But I would like it in a Macro so I can run it every time we update our accounts.

Thanks,

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODPml.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Evaluate( _
"SUMIFS($H$15:$H$12729,$F$15:$F$12729,""<> 52202001"", $F$15:$F$12729,""<> 51701001"")")
```

EDIT: in the worksheet code module for the sheet with data:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then

        v = Me.Evaluate("SUMIFS($H$15:$H$12729,$F$15:$F$12729,""<> 52202001"", $F$15:$F$12729,""<> 51701001"")")

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = v

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. You really are the best. Just one more thing, if I wanted to have this sum on every change in region (Column A) and have this displayed on sheet2 what would I add in?